# Anyone knows what I could do to this javascript code to make it more reliable?

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, esp8266

I don't really know all that much about javascript at all yet, I just recently started learning it bc I needed it for a microcontroller project where we needed to use an MCU with network capabilities so apart from making the mcu code I was tasked with creating the web pages it would provide to the user.
In one instance I made a section where the user would be able to see all (actually most, at least the ones I thought of importance to them) the parameters for the Led matrix that they get to set up. The problem is that, in order to load the parameters I used a method that I believe isn't really efficient, and the fact that I still don't know much about js doesn't help it. Does any of this seem to have a much easier solution to you?

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="column1" class="column">
  </div>

  <div class="column middle">
    <h3 style="color: rgb(187, 187, 187);">Parámetros guardados: </h3>
    <div class="guardado">
    <p >Mensaje guardado inicial: <span id="mensaje"></span></p>
    <p >Brillo guardado: <span id="brightness"></span></p>
    <p >Velocidad guardada: <span id="speed"></span></p>
    <p >Alineación: <span id="text_align"></span></p>
    <p >Modo operando: <span id="MODO"></span></p>
    <p >Tiempo entre mensajes (M2): <span id="TIME"></span></p>
    <p >Efecto (M1): <span id="EM1"></span></p>
    <p >Efecto inicio (M2): <span id="E1M2"></span></p>
    <p >Efecto salida (M2): <span id="E2M2"></span></p>
</div>
</div>
  
 <script>
    //Load parameters
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();           //Message
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "/mensaje", true);
    xhttp.send();

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();           //Brightness
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("brightness").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "/brillo_guardado.txt", true);
    xhttp.send();

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();           //Speed
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML += "%";
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "/velocidad_guardado.txt", true);
    xhttp.send();   

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();           //MODE
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("MODO").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "/modo_guardado.txt", true);
    xhttp.send();   

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();           //Text alignment
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("text_align").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "/alineacion_guardado.txt", true);
    xhttp.send();

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();         //var initial_time
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("TIME").innerHTML = this.response;
        document.getElementById("TIME").innerHTML += "ms";
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "/tiempo_guardado.txt");
    xhttp.send();

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();         //EFFECT MODE 1
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("EM1").innerHTML = this.response;
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "/effecto_modo1_guardado.txt");
    xhttp.send();

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();         //EFFECT 1 MODE 2
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("E1M2").innerHTML = this.response;
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "/effecto1_m2_guardado.txt");
    xhttp.send();
    
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();         //EFFECT 2 MODE 2
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("E2M2").innerHTML = this.response;
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "/effecto2_m2_guardado.txt");
    xhttp.send();
    
</script>
```

[This is what it looks like after loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0nPO.png)

The page is going to be asking the mcu for several parameters it has stored and then it'll display them.

Comment: JS code but tagged C.  I don't see any C code here.

Comment: My bad, I was thinking of the code for the esp8266

Comment: Reliable? Efficient? It isn't clear what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Reliable as in, is there a way for this to load the parameters faster from a server or this is as good as it gets?

Comment: @TheMainMan Thank you for removing the tag.

Comment: It's asynchrone so it should not be to much of a performance problem to do multiple http requests. I don't know the API, if it has an option to get all your data with 1 requests it would be preferable ofcourse. Also the code is a bit old fashioned and there are [more readable ways](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to retrieve data from a server.

Comment: You might want to factor your code to keep it a little more DRY, but if that's the whole thing, I'd leave it like that. No need to fuss about some repetition unless it really becomes a problem.

Comment: Your API should provide an endpoint that lets you fetch all these parameters at once, in a single request. Much simpler, and less straining on the MCU. Also you might want to just prepopulate the form when serving the html, not even using any js for this.

Comment: It seems like a must to fetch all the parameters at once so I'm gonna take a look and see how I can do that with the esp. Also for the prepopulate thing, I was completely unaware of the fact that you can do that. Thanks people :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code can be cleaned up a lot:

```
function loadText(elementId, url, suffix = ""){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = this.responseText + suffix;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xhttp.send();
}

//Load parameters
loadText("mensaje",    "/mensaje");
loadText("brightness", "/brillo_guardado.txt");
loadText("speed",      "/velocidad_guardado.txt", "%");
loadText("MODO",       "/modo_guardado.txt");
loadText("text_align", "/alineacion_guardado.txt");
loadText("TIME",       "/tiempo_guardado.txt", "ms");
loadText("EM1",        "/effecto_modo1_guardado.txt");
loadText("E1M2",       "/effecto1_m2_guardado.txt");
loadText("E2M2",       "/effecto2_m2_guardado.txt");
```

When you're repeating code like that, put it into a function.

Other than that, there's not much you can do to make it faster, as you're loading every individual string from a separate url.

Instead of the old-fashioned `XMLHttpRequest`, you can also make use of the [`fetch` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch):

```
function loadText(elementId, url, suffix = ""){
    fetch(url).then((response) => {
        document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = response + suffix;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks man :) I really didn't think about just making that into a function. I'm gonna have to look deeper into the fetch API 'cause I got my ass clapped when I tried to use it with the mcu so thanks for that one as well